# What's the difference between a predefined global variable and a keyword in javascript?

Tags: javascript

For example, I see that `undefined` is described like a predefined global variable, while `null` is described like a keyword.

What's the difference?

Answer (score 1):

`null` is not a keyword; it's a **special [literal value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Null_literal)**, like `true`. [See the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-null-literals).

`undefined` is not a keyword either. First, it's the **name of a [global property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined)** with some special behaviors: it is non-configurable and non-writable (in modern browsers), meaning you cannot change its value. [See the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-undefined).

Second, it's a **special value** which is the value of the `undefined` property, the value of uninitialized variables, the return value of functions without explicit `return` statements, and what the `void` operator evaluates to.

Third, it's a **type**, whose only value is the undefined value.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, some identifiers are reserved words and cannot be used as variables or function names those called keywords e.g `break, case, catch, continue, debugger, default, delete, do, else, false, finally, for, function` these are some reserved keywords in javaScript.

Whereas A variable declared outside a function, becomes GLOBAL. A global variable has global scope: All scripts and functions on a web page can access it.

Comment: You didn't answer the question as regards either `undefined` or `null`.